# Start and Stop core.async Interval

Tags: clojure, core.async

consider the following core-async code. It prints the string "tick" every 2 seconds:

```
(go-loop []
  (<! (timeout 2000))
  (prn "tick")
  (recur))
```

I'm looking for a possibility to start and stop the interval from outside via functions.

The only thing that came to my mind was this:

```
(def running (atom false))

(defn start []
  (reset! running true)
  (go (loop []
         (<! (timeout 2000))
         (prn "tick")
         (when @running (recur)))))

(defn stop []
  (reset! running false))
```

Is this the way to go? Or would you do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as a])

(defn interval [f msecs]
  (let [timing (a/chan)
        kickoff
        #(a/go
           (a/<! (a/timeout msecs))
           (a/>! timing true))]
    (a/go-loop []
      (when (a/<! timing)
        (a/go (f))
        (kickoff)
        (recur)))
    (kickoff)
    #(a/close! timing)))
```

Example:

```
(let [i (interval #(prn "tick") 2000)]
  (Thread/sleep 7000)
  (i))
;; "tick"
;; "tick"
;; "tick"
;;=> nil
```

This way, all your state is local and is handled via channels and go blocks, rather than using a global atom. Since the work done in each iteration of the loop is more or less constant, your actual interval time should be fairly close to the number of `msecs` you pass in.

Or if you want to guarantee that the different calls to `f` are executed in chronological order, you could do something like this instead:

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as a])

(defn interval [f msecs]
  (let [action (a/chan (a/dropping-buffer 1))
        timing (a/chan)
        kickoff
        #(a/go
           (a/<! (a/timeout msecs))
           (a/>! timing true))]
    (a/go-loop []
      (when (a/<! action)
        (f)
        (recur)))
    (a/go-loop []
      (if (a/<! timing)
        (do
          (a/>! action true)
          (kickoff)
          (recur))
        (a/close! action)))
    (kickoff)
    #(a/close! timing)))
```

(The usage of this function is the same as that of my earlier `interval` function.)

Here all the calls to `f` are in the same loop. I'm using a dropping buffer, so if a call to `f` takes longer than `msecs`, future calls may start getting dropped to keep up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, you could go

```
(defn start []
 (let [ctl (chan 0 )]
   (go-loop []
     (alt!
       (timeout 2000) (do
                     (prn "tick")
                     (recur))
        ctl (prn "Exit ")))
   ctl))


(let [w (start) ]
  (Thread/sleep 7000)
  (>!! w "stop"))

;;=>     "tick"
         "tick"
         "Exit"
```

You don't need to define state in namespace. Start function is returning chan to do stop in future.